# Reading a JSON file in JavaScript "Undefined" object

Tags: javascript, json, object, undefined

I have created a JSON file with an object in it and I am trying to access the specific elements of the object. Although I get the object when I try to get the specific value I get "undefined".
Any idea what is the problem here?

Here is my parameters.json file

```
{"employee": { "name": "sonoo", "salary": 56000, "married": true  }}
```

And Here is how I retrieve it from my JS file

```
fetch("parameters.json")
        .then(function(resp){
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            
            console.log(data.name);
        })
```

Here is what I see in the console : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVyQ.png)

Comment: Your object does not _have_ any `name` property on the top level, the only thing it has there is `employee`.

Comment: **You can't completely ignore whole layers of your data structure!**. `data` is an object with an `employee` property and only an `employee` property.

Comment: `data` is an object with an `employee` property which has a value that's also an object, so you need to access `data.employee.name`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to see it from the screenshot, the path is `data.employee.name` not `data.name`.

Try this:

```
fetch("parameters.json")
        .then(function(resp){
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);

            console.log(data.employee); // Whole employee

            console.log(data.employee.name); // Employee name

            console.log(data.name); // Undefined as it does not exist
        })
```